# ERROR Could not load Json file: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null} in angular

Tags: json, angular

I have this code to load a json file on a specific api to make login form, after making login structure Iam trying to get data from a specific api, but the problem is not responsing the json file which contain api url:

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {IAppConfig} from './_models/app.config.model';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {

static settings: IAppConfig;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

  load() {

  const jsonFile = `config/config${environment.production ? '' : 
   '.dev'}.json`;
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log('inside promise');
  console.log(jsonFile);
  this.http.get<IAppConfig>(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: 
  IAppConfig) => {
  console.log(response);// here reponse fails
   if (!this.isInstanceOfIAppConfig(response)) {
      reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': Json format does not 
       match config`);
    }
   AppConfig.settings = response;
   resolve();
  }).catch((response: any) => {
    reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': 
  ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
   });
  });
  }

 isInstanceOfIAppConfig(object: any): object is IAppConfig {
 console.log(object);
 return 'apiBaseUrl' in object;
  }

}
```

For Which config.dev.json file contains the url api:
    {
    "apiBaseUrl": "https://getDatafromSpecificApi/api/v1"
    }

Comment: why are you not importing config in a more classical way ? `import { config } from './config/config.json'` ? Then after your imports you can define your api url as `const API_URL = config.apiBaseUrl`

Comment: What does your json look like?

Comment: TLDR; "json" in question header is invalid.

Comment: @BernardPagoaga I have added import { config } from './config/config.json'; Note: that I have added config folder in the project file directly not in src , So I returns error that 'cannot find module file config/config.json'

Comment: @MikeTung  my config.json file contains  :{ "apiBaseUrl": "https://getDatafromSpecificApi/api/v1" }

Comment: You should adapt the path of your config.json file (same was as you did with your environment folder)

Comment: import {config} from 'config/config.json';
import {config} from './config/config.json'; import {config} from '../config/config.json';
(I have tried it in these three ways no one is taking the correct file)